# SQL - Toad for Oracle v11.6. - trying to select the top row of for each unique value in a particular field data after using Distinct

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct

hopefully the following information helps more here. I've run the following code in Toad for oracle:

```
select distinct cc_orig, cc_base, txn_orig, txn_base 
from table a
```

which has returned the information along the lines of

```
cc_orig      cc_base        txn_orig      txn_base

GBP          CAD             50           35
GBP          CAD             75           45
GBP          CAD             20           10
EUR          CAD             10            8
EUR          CAD             13           11
AUD          CAD             90           50
AUD          CAD             15            5
AUD          CAD             80           45
```

I would like to only pull back one row for each unique value within cc_orig field (it doesn't matter which row it is), so the new results would look something like the following:

```
cc_orig      cc_base        txn_orig      txn_base
GBP          CAD             50           35
EUR          CAD             10            8
AUD          CAD             90           50
```

Hopefully this makes sense and somebody can help - I think this is similar to Distinct On in Postgres, but this doesn't appear to work in Toad

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select cc_orig, cc_base, txn_orig, txn_base
from (select cc_orig, cc_base, txn_orig, txn_base,
             row_number() over (partition by cc_orig order by cc_orig) as seqnum
      from table a
     ) a
where seqnum = 1;
```

Notice that you don't need the `select distinct`.  The `row_number()` is only choosing one (arbitrary) row anyway.